# Manipulating the HTML DOM similar to jQuery with C# and ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, dom

I have a page with a table that is populated from a database. It looks a little something like this:

```
System   Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep  Oct   Nov   Dec
1        x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x    x     x     x
2        x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x    x     x     x
6        x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x    x     x     x
```

Each cell inside the table (IE each 'x' on the above diagram) contains a textbox that the user needs to enter a value into. I dynamically give each textbox an ID using the column title and the system number for example 'feb2', ' mar6', 'oct1'.

At the bottom of the page is a save button that when pressed, will update the values in the database for all the systems and all the months.

**My problem is this: How can I get the values of the text boxes and call an sql function to update the values without first knowing the IDs of the text boxes?**

Here is an example of what I would like to do in jQuery (a language I am much more familiar with):

```
function saveValues(){
    var rows = $("#SystemTargetsTable tr:not(:first-child)"); // skip the header row
    var systemID;
    var jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec;

    rows.each(function(index) {        
    systemID = $(this).attr('id').substring(6);

    jan = $('#Jan' + systemID).val();
    feb = $('#Feb' + systemID).val();
    mar = $('#Mar' + systemID).val();
    apr = $('#Apr' + systemID).val();
    may = $('#May' + systemID).val();
    jun = $('#Jun' + systemID).val();
    jul = $('#Jul' + systemID).val();
    aug = $('#Aug' + systemID).val();
    sep = $('#Sep' + systemID).val();
    oct = $('#Oct' + systemID).val();
    nov = $('#Nov' + systemID).val();
    dec = $('#Dec' + systemID).val();

    //ONCE I HAVE THE VALUES FOR EACH MONTH I WOULD LIKE TO CALL AN UPDATE STATEMENT USING THE SYSTEM ID. ONLY OF COURSES I CANNOT DO TIS FROM JAVASCRIPT!
  }); 
}
```

Thankyou for your time. I hope this all made sense!

Answer (score 0):

make this table server control, with runat="server" attribute & giving ID, e.g; tbl1,
Then loop though table row

> ```
>   for (var i = 0; i<tbl1.Rows.Count; i++)
>              {
>                  var txtJan = tbl1.Rows[i].FindControl("Jan" + i.ToString());
> ```
>
> `var janValue =txtJan.Text;`
>
> ```
>              }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can not update and sql table row  without knowing the ID of unique column Which in your case is the system column.
Here is what I do :
By the time you are populating you table with the dynamic text box for each row you assign the id of the textbox = system id value of that row.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="System.ID_Value(FromDB)"  value="Month_Value_(value from DB)" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

then on the click event of the save button 

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var row in Table1.Rows)
        {
            string[] allkeys = Request.Form.AllKeys;
            foreach (string key in allkeys)
            {
                if (key.ToUpper().StartsWith("System_ID"))
                {
                    var ID = Convert.ToInt32(key.Split('_')[1]);           
                }
                if (key.ToUpper().StartsWith("MOnth_Value"))
                {
                    var Jan = Convert.ToInt32(key.Split('_')[2]);
                    var feb = Convert.ToInt32(key.Split('_')[3]);
                }
                // and so on then you call the update method
            }  
        }
    }
```